# Does PostgreSQL support subtransactions?

Tags: postgresql, transaction

Does PostgreSQL support subtransactions?
From DOC

> "Note that a transaction can hold conflicting locks on the same row,
>   even in different subtransactions;" (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-ROWS)

On internet i didn't find such info, excepting PlPy or plv8 extensions or discussions on AST on PG WIKI.

If yes, how they are used - any doc?

Comment: Those are [savepoints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-savepoint.html)

Comment: OP, note that savepoints and subtransactions are functionally equivalent just using different syntactic sugar to get the job done.